# The report does not fit in width in Power BI REPORT Server

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

There are several reports in Power BI REPORT Server. When opening a report from different devices, the report does not fit in width. If you click view by width everything works. How to make the report automatically fit the width of the screen when opened on any device?
Thanks for your answer in advance/